# В CSS есть блок в блоке, в каждом есть надпись. В дочернем блоке центруется, в основном нет. Как отцентровать в CSS в зависимости от размеров?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
body {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.temp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.name {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

.tommer {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
}

.temp-2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <div class="tommer"><p>Hello!</p></div>
  <span class="name">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="temp-2">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

В CSS есть блок в блоке, в каждом есть надпись. В дочернем желтом блоке центруется, в основном нет. Как отцентровать текст в красном блоке в CSS в зависимости от размеров и не затрагивая текст в желтом?
Уверен, что где-то мелочная закавыка начинающего уровня, но мозг я сломал. Я новичок, сорри.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: Спасибо, что указали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто, нужно добавить `text-align: left;`, тому элементы, где вам центрирование не нужно.

```css
body {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.temp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.name {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

.tommer {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: left; /* Возвращаем пропорции значение left */
}

.temp-2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <div class="tommer"><p>Hello!</p></div>
  <span class="name">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="temp-2">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Как мы знаем, `text-align` наследуется на дочерние элементы, так что нам нужно просто добавить своё значение `text-align` дочернему элементу, в котором текст не должен быть отцентирован.

Comment: Все, спасибо. Все реально просто.

Comment: @Alexander если вам не жалко, поставьте галочку рядом с вопросом, чтобы отметить что он, решил вашу задачу. (Если что они снизу голосов)